# Set lower limit to incoming new channels in LND

Tags: lightning-network

For now, any remote node can open a channel to my LND node and my node will always happily accept the channel.

However, I've seen in the past that other nodes would have limits in what channel sizes they accept. E.G. a node might not accept any channel that's smaller than 2'000'000 sats.

How can I setup my node to behave in a similar way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at lnd.conf (or in particular at the [sample-lnd.conf line 138](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/c5357d383d39a6a7abc970ff442c350a6bff6acc/sample-lnd.conf#L138)) you will see the following:

```
; The smallest channel size (in satoshis) that we should accept. Incoming
; channels smaller than this will be rejected, default value 20000.
; minchansize=
```

which means if you remove the `;` and set a value in satoshis your node will reject smaller channels.

After changing `lnd.conf` you have to restart your node and then it should behave in the way you want